Unit Disks problem
Good day, I'm faced with a problem that I don't understand how to approach. I would be grateful if you could tell me at least the direction in which to think.
Three circles of unit radius are given with centers at points X, Y, Z. It is known that these circles do not have a common intersection, but they intersect in pairs. Let A be a vertex from the intersection of circles X, Y such that circles of unit radius with centers in A, X, Z do not have a common intersection, but have a pairwise intersection, and circles of unit radius with centers in A, Y, Z do not have a common intersection, but they have a pairwise intersection. The marks of the remaining necessary points are shown in the figure. Let $z_m$ be the center point of the arc ($a_1 b_1$), $x_m$ be the center point of the arc ($a_1 c_1$), $y_m$ is the center point of the arc ($b_1 c_1$). It must be proved that if $|a z_m|\leqslant 1$, as well as $|a x_m|\leqslant 1$ and $|a y_m|> 1$, then $|a_2 b_2| \leqslant 1$.
Geogebra drawing
Picture for the problem
